# "Available memory less than 15MB" error when launching Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I purchased Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines in the sale today, but when I try to launch it I get the following error message:

**Available memory less than 15MB!!!!**

This is definitely not true. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to patch the game, and sadly, the official updates that Steam grabs only go so far. [Vinay's answer has a link to a 64 bit patch for systems with > 4GB of RAM](https://iain.cx/articles/bloodlines/index.html?part5), and I'd also **strongly** recommend grabbing Wesp's unofficial patch, version 7.9 (or above).

[You can download it here.](http://www.patches-scrolls.de/patch/4647)

It should be noted that so long as you don't enable the 'Plus' patch option, the Wesp patch *does not* make substantial gameplay changes, but *does* fix a large number of broken quests and dialogs, restore some cut content, improve performance, and generally makes for a *much* better gameplay experience.

Additionally, since I'm assuming based on 'the sale today' that you have the Steam version, here's a few notes on installing the Wesp patch for the Steam edition of VTM:B:

> 1) Run Steam as Administrator.
>   2) Start the unpatched game once, so it will fetch any additional Steam-files and initialize itself.
>   3) Quit the game.
>   4) Now disable "Steam Community In Game" and "Automatic Update" inside Steam (for this game).
>   5) Install our patch to **\steamapps\common\vampire the masquerade - bloodlines** on your computer.
>   6) Leave both "Steam Community In Game" & "Automatic Update" for Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines disabled, there won't be any new updates anyway.

**Finally**, if you'd like to play the game at a real, modern, *widescreen* resolution, you'll need to grab [this file](http://www.fileplanet.com/156598/150000/fileinfo/Vampire-The-Masquerade:-Bloodlines---Resolution-Patcher), and install it.

Comment: I believe the Unofficial Patch by Wesp5 already contains a custom resolution and widescreen patch. Does that differ from the [resolution patcher you linked here](http://www.fileplanet.com/156598/150000/fileinfo/Vampire-The-Masquerade%3a-Bloodlines---Resolution-Patcher)?

Comment: @galacticninja Wesp's patch didn't always include the widescreen patcher. I haven't looked into it in a year or so, but I believe it's been baked in now and is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the game running on systems with 4 GB+ RAM. To solve it, download the patch for your game version at this [link](https://iain.cx/articles/bloodlines/index.html?part5)

EDIT: You can also try running the game in compatibility mode for Windows XP and see if it solves your problem. Right click on your game's .exe file, go to Properties->Compatibility tab, select "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and choose Windows XP SP2 from the drop down list.

Comment: Compatability mode usually doesn't solve these problems. You need application compatability shims created in microsofts application compatability toolkit. But if a vendor patch solves the problem then that is easier