# How do I install Vampire the Masquerade Bloodlines unofficial patches?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I have installed Vampire the Masquerade: Bloodlines, via Steam, on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

I found this question: ["Available memory less than 15MB" error when launching Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53171/available-memory-less-than-15mb-1-when-launching)

I followed most of these instructions, and the game runs great! 
The "memory bug" patch ran without a problem.
The "resolution patcher" ran without a problem.
I set the executable to run in compatibility mode so the opening animations are visible.
Still no problems...

However, I would like to try installing the unofficial patches.
I downloaded patch 8.1 from here:
http://www.patches-scrolls.de/vampire_bloodlines.php

When I try to execute `VTMBup81b.exe`, I get a popup window that says:

```
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're
running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an
x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the
software publisher.
```

Then, I tried to be clever.
I copied the directory where Bloodlines was installed onto a 32-bit Windows XP Virtual Machine.  I copied the patch there.
When I tried to execute the patch file under the XP VM, I simply got "Cannot execute VTMBup81b.exe" (on the command line, not a Windows popup).

I tried the same thing with the version 7.9 patch, just to be sure, and I got the same results.

How can I get this patch to install?

Comment: Try changing the compability mode on the patch itself.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you check if you aren't missing any DLLs with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. it turns out that somehow there was an issue downloading the patches -- both the 8.1 and 7.9 -- in the first place.
They were each 41k in size. On a whim, I tried re-downloading, and the 8.1 patch was over 200MB this time (!).

After re-downloading and getting the 200MB version, the patch installer started up fine.

Really not sure what happened here. But I'm all set now.